# Frequency of elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to write a code that finds the frequency of characters in a String entered in the method (`phraseList()` is an already working method that takes a word and puts each character in an `arrayList`)
and returns in a new `List` that has the letters and their frequency, my code below;

```
public List <String> ltrfrq(String phrase){
List <String> list0 = new ArrayList<String>();
int count = 1;
List <String> list = phraseList(phrase.toUpperCase());
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
  for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){
    if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
      count++;
    }
  }
  if(list.get(i).equals(" ")){
    list0.add("Space" + "-" + count);
  }
  else{
    list0.add(list.get(i) + "-" + count);
  }
  count = 1;
}
return list0;
  }
}
```

My problem however is that it returns all the letters and although I have tried many methods to remove them like using the `remove()` method, it still does not work, I had something like

```
list.remove(list.get(i));
i--;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried a HashMap<Character, Integer>?

Comment: @JabariDash I'm not coversant with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HashMaps are key-value pairs. But the keys are unique. So you cannot have duplicate keys. Kind of like a dictionary, you can update the value (definition) of a word, but you won't have that word listed twice.

Watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j442WG8YzM4

Read: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/

Output:

```
{a=4, b=3, c=2, d=1}
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to traverse the map.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class F {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "aaaabbbccd";

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = frequency(string);

    System.out.println(map);
  }

  public static HashMap<Character, Integer> frequency(String string) {
    int length = string.length();
    char c;

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      c = string.charAt(i);

      if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);

      } else {

        map.put(c, 1);
      }
    }

    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, this is nice but is there no other way to do this than with HashMaps?,  I'm saying this because I'm not conversant with it yet although I know that I would have to learn it anyways.

Comment: You can...i think the algorithm would just be considerably more complex...probably more complex than just learning how a hashmap works, but ill see.

Comment: @EOluwatobiloba using a hash map is the go-to solution to this kind of problem. You should learn it asap if you consider yourself a serious programmer. Traversing lists to check if some character was already seen is far from optimal and is considered bad practice. Don't do this kind of thing in a job interview unless you don't want to be hired :-)

Comment: I agree. As you can see, it is a lot more complex, and prone to error. HashMaps are a FUNDAMENTAL data structure that speeds  up almost any algorithm (that it can be used in).

Comment: Thanks, but I am still a student and have much to learn so I will learn it of course

Comment: Im a student too haha! and like 9 times out of 10 in your interviewing process, HashMaps will come up. I wish someone told me sooner!

Answer (score 2):

If I could only use List data structures (and my own custom one), this is how I would do it. I would redefine all of the add, remove functions to compensate for duplicate entries.

Output:

```
[{a=4}, {b=3}, {c=2}, {d=1}]
```

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class F {

  static class Entry {
    char character;
    int count;

    public Entry(char c, int i) {
      character = c;
      count = i;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "{" + character + "=" + count + "}";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "aaaabbbccd";

    List<Entry> list = frequency(string);

    System.out.println(list);
  }


  public static List<Entry> frequency(String string) {
    int length = string.length();
    char c;
    Entry entry;

    List<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      c = string.charAt(i);

      // add to list
      add(c, list);
    }

    return list;
  }

  public static void add(char c, List<Entry> list) {

    // If the list does not contain the character
    if (!contains(c, list)) {
      list.add(new Entry(c, 1));

    } else {

      // Find the entry
      int index = find(c, list);

      // If we found the entry's indes
      if (index >= 0) {

        // Get the entry
        Entry temp = list.get(index);

        temp.count++;           // Increment its count
        list.remove(index);     // Delete old 1
        list.add(index, temp);  // Insert new 1
      }
    }
  }

  // Finds the index of an entry thats associated with a character
  public static int find(char c, List<Entry> list) {
    int index = -1;
    int length = list.size();


    Entry temp;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      temp = list.get(i);

      if (temp.character == c) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }


    return index;
  }

  // Remove an Entry from list that is associate with a given character
  public static List<Entry> remove(char c, List<Entry> list) {

    for (Entry entry : list) {
      if (entry.character == c) {
        list.remove(entry);
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  // Get the entry that correlates to a give character in the list
  public static Entry get(char c, List<Entry> list) {
    Entry entryToReturn = null;

    for (Entry entry : list) {
      if (entry.character == c) {
        entryToReturn = entry;
        break;
      }
    }

    return entryToReturn;
  }


  // Checks if the list contains the character
  public static boolean contains(char c, List<Entry> list) {
    boolean contains = false;

    for (Entry entry : list) {
      if (entry.character == c) {
        contains = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return contains;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works thanks, and I know have a clue to another way too, thank you

Comment: No problem. But really consider those HashMaps!

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is the easier way to solving this problem. If you have to use List, you can check if the character exist in list0 first. If the character is not exist in list0 then count for its frequency.

Updated Code :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList <String> list0 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 1;
        //List <String> list = phraseList(phrase.toUpperCase());\
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("a");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("a");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
             for (String s: list0){
                 if (s.contains(list.get(i).trim()))
                     isDuplicate =true;
             }

            if (!isDuplicate){

                  for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){
                    if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
                      count++;
                    }
                  }
                  if(list.get(i).equals("/s")){
                    list0.add("Space" + "-" + count);
                  }
                  else{
                    list0.add(list.get(i) + "-" + count);
                  }
                  count = 1;     
            }
        }
        for (String a: list0)
            System.out.println(a);          
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is complete or not but I've checked it and it did not work

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: The same as I got without the if statement

Comment: contains() in List behave different from it in String. Try updated code. It works on my side.

Comment: About the .contains(), it gives me an error message saying it's not from the required .class files? Do you know what that is please?

Comment: Can you update with the entire trace log of the error?

Comment: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
   referenced from required .class files

Comment: @E Oluwatobiloba, try it with the updated code.  I don't have the phraseList(), so i manually insert item into List.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using the new method `merge()` available on Java8 `Map`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CountLetterFrequency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ltrfrq("abacacdea"));
    }

    public static Map<Character, Integer> ltrfrq(String phrase){
        Map<Character, Integer> frqMap = new HashMap<>(); 
        for(int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++){
            frqMap.merge(phrase.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);
        }
        return frqMap;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{a=4, b=1, c=2, d=1, e=1}
```

With the method `merge()`, when the item is not in the map, it just adds it, which in this case will add `key=charAt(i),value=1`. On the other hand, if the key is already on the map, merge calls a function passing both current and new values, and updates the map with the result of this function.

`Integer::sum` is a method reference, since the `merge` method expects a function with two parameters, we could rewrite it as `(currV,newV) -> currV+newV`.

Now, if you wish, you can use the new `Stream` API instead. First, convert the `String` to an `IntStream`, then map each `int` to a `Character`, then collect the result on a `HashMap` and return it. The method `ltrfrq` would be as follows:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> ltrfrq(String phrase){
    return phrase.chars()
        .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
        .collect(HashMap::new,
            (m,k) -> m.merge(k, 1, Integer::sum),
            Map::putAll);
}
```